# Filter Custom Array time optimization

Tags: arrays, swift, string, filter

I have to filter array of articles based on a keyword(string) in article's description. Filtering is taking 2-3 seconds on 1500+ elements's array of type Article and 2000+ words in each article description.

I am using below code; i also tried predicate but didn't worked for me.

```
let searchResult = articlesList.filter {
    let article = $0

    let filterByName = article.title.lowercased().range(of: text.lowercased())
    let filterByDescription = article.body.lowercased().range(of: (text.lowercased()))
    if ((filterByName != nil) || filterByDescription != nil) {
        if !articlesList.contains(article) {
            articlesList.append(article)
        }
    }
    else {
        let index = articlesList.index(of: article)
        if index != nil {
            articlesList.remove(at: index!)
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

I want filter time max to 0.3 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a <strike>bit</strike> lot faster

```
let searchResult = articles.filter{ $0.title.range(of: text, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil 
                                 || $0.body.range(of: text, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you perform changes on the collection you are filtering. You shouldn't have `articleList.remove()` and `articleList.append()` in the filter function. The way `filter` works is that you just return `true` for every element that you want to keep in the filtered collection (in your case `searchResult`) and `false` for the rest.

Try this code:

```
let searchResult = articlesList.filter { article in
    let filterByName = article.title!.lowercased().range(of: text.lowercased())
    let filterByDescription = article.body!.lowercased().range(of: (text.lowercased()))
    if ((filterByName != nil) || filterByDescription != nil){
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```